# Is there one word for 'six and half-a-dozen'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was asked to visit a different client last night, other than my usual one. I said 'Yes, sure. It's six and half-a-dozen.' (In the nature of my work, I can choose what I do; it was a request not a demand.)

I meant that, to me, there was nothing to choose in terms of travel distance or client requirements, so I was happy to accept either assignment.

But could I have said 'it's six and half a dozen' in one word ?

'Yes, sure. It's _ _ _ _ _ '

Comment: The usual expression is '[It's] six of one, half a dozen of the other'.  Your reduced version does not appear very often in Google searches.

Comment: "six of one and half a dozen of the other" usually refers to two things that are equally good or bad. I don't  see the choice here between two things.

Comment: 'Like for like' (hyphenated in 'Collins') certainly carries the exact meaning, but doesn't really sound quite right (it's not over-respectful for one thing) here.

Comment: The one word is "seventy-eight".

Comment: Twelve. The answer is twelve.

Comment: Six and a half dozen is 78. Six plus half a dozen is 12. 'Six and half a dozen' is a choice of one or the other, so it is 6.

Comment: I've also heard "six and two threes" to mean "there's nothing to choose between the options", but I have a feeling that it's an East Yorkshire expression.

Comment: “Tomayto, tomahto”? Not quite the same thing (and still two words), but could work.

Comment: Can’t think of one word but, “Yeah sure, it doesn’t matter.” or “Yeah sure, either one.”  are pretty short.

Comment: One you don't hear much anymore:  [comme ci comme ça](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comme_ci_comme_%C3%A7a)

Comment: @HotLicks 6.5 x 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider: *It's **all good**.*

> A phrase used to express general approval, unconcern, or disinterest.
>
> - *Steve: "I'm so sorry, John, but I scratched your car when I was parking."*
>     *John: "It's all good, Steve. Don't worry about it."*
> - *A: "Is lasagna all right for dinner?"*
>     *B: "Yeah, it's all good."*
>
> <sub>[The Free Dictionary by FARLEX](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it%27s+all+good)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing *exactly* what you were trying to convey, it's difficult to come up with an idiomatic expression with the right nuance.

There is the expression "six of one and half-a-dozen of the other", but it's not used in the situation you describe. I've encountered it when describing points of view which are equally valid, or two sides of an argument; or when *you* are making an active choice between two alternatives. It's not generally used when the (potential) choice has already been made for you.

If you were really saying that as far as you were concerned there was no difference in what you were asked to do — same travel, similar work, whatever — then **all the same** might be more appropriate: "It's all the same to me." This does have a slightly dismissive air and could easily be accompanied with a shrug.

> **be all the same to**
>
> Be unimportant to (someone) what happens.
>   *‘it was all the same to me where it was being sold’*
>
> [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be_all_the_same_to)

Comment: "Is there one word for 'six and half-a-dozen'?"

Comment: @Edwin I guess you're going to supply one, then. Sorry you think this answer isn't useful.

Comment: The trouble is that people who're trying to answer accurately are disadvantaged by those taking liberties with the question.

Answer (score 1):

When there's nothing to choose between one option or the other; neither is significantly better or worse than the other, you can say "*Yes, sure. It's immaterial*".

> **immaterial**
>   *adjective*
>
> 1. unimportant under the circumstances; irrelevant.
>      "*the difference in our ages is immaterial*"
>
>    *synonyms*: *irrelevant*, *unimportant*, *inconsequential*, *insignificant*, of no matter/moment, of little account, beside the point, not to the point, neither here nor there, inapposite, not pertinent, not germane;
>
> [Source: *define immaterial* on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+immaterial)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that there is a word for quite what you describe here, but taking the phrase of 'six of one. half a dozen of the other', you could use the word [**indistinguishable**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/indistinguishable)

In terms of your two clients, I doubt that you could describe them as **indistinguishable**, but in terms of requirements they may be described so.

> To the untrained eye, they are **indistinguishable** one from the other.

You could also describe them as [**comparable**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/comparable), which might be a better fit.

> The planet Pluto is **comparable** in size to our Moon